# SignarlR Two Hubs must not share the same name

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

We are developing a server application that uses SigalR libraries at core. 
When I try to get current server context, I got this error below. Is there anyone who knows the reason of this error? Thank you.

1) It's not an MVC application, its a console application.

2) We don't use App_Start ort App_Code folders.

**The startup class which is inside of the console app.:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

**Here is my constructor which is inside of a class library. And server starts itself.**

```
public ServerBase()
{
    serverURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerURI"];
    StartServer();
    serverContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerBase>();
}
```

**ErrorMessage:**

> Two Hubs must not share the same name.
>   'Core.MessageTransmitter.ServerBase, Core.MessageTransmitter,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
>   'Core.MessageTransmitter.ServerBase, Core.MessageTransmitter,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' both share the
>   name 'ServerBase'.

**Stack trace:**

> at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.BuildHubsCache()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.ReflectedHubDescriptorProvider.TryGetHub(String
>   hubName, HubDescriptor& descriptor)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetHub>b__0(IHubDescriptorProvider
>   p)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.DefaultHubManager.GetHub(String hubName)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubManagerExtensions.EnsureHub(IHubManager
>   hubManager, String hubName, IPerformanceCounter[] counters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(String
>   hubName)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ConnectionManager.GetHubContextT
>   at Core.MessageTransmitter.ServerBase..ctor() in
>   C:\ReklamUssuProjects\MenuBoard-DevBranch\ReklamUssu.Core\Core.MessageTransmitter\ServerBase.cs:line
>   28    at Core.MessageTransmitter.ServerBase..ctor(Logger logger) in
>   C:\ReklamUssuProjects\MenuBoard-DevBranch\ReklamUssu.Core\Core.MessageTransmitter\ServerBase.cs:line
>   30    at Core.ContextManager.ServerContext.Initialize(String name,
>   Type messageBroker, String serviceAddress, String metaDataAddress) in
>   C:\ReklamUssuProjects\MenuBoard-DevBranch\ReklamUssu.Core\Core.Context\ServerContext.cs:line
>   22    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ServerContext , String ,
>   Type , Object , Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)    at
>   MenuBoard.AppHostConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\ReklamUssuProjects\MenuBoard-DevBranch\ReklamUssu.MenuBoard\MenuBoard.AppHostConsole\Program.cs:line
>   29

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using? `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` tells me that you are trying to use SignalR 2.2.2 or similar on Asp.NET Core which is not a supported scenario. The version of SignalR to use for Asp.NET Core is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/ (note that at the moment the latest version is alpha1)

Comment: the version is: 2.1.0

Comment: I guess I was misled by the `signalr-core` tag (which I removed) and the first  sentence: 'We are developing a server application that uses SigalR libraries at core'. Both made me think you were running SignalR for ASP.NET on ASP.NET Core (which is not a supported scenario)

Comment: sorry for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about Owin. We have 2 applications. First one is WCF server, second one is SignalR service. When we start SignalR service first, there is no problem. We have solved the problem just this way. I think there is an intersection point between these servers.